# Unable to scp files from local machine into vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I'm trying to scp files from my machines desktop into my vagrant box but I seem to keep running into this error.

```
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

I looked into my vagrant file and found this line:

```
 Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
# within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
# accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

I've tried running these commands and have gotten the following errors respectively:

```
scp -P 80 nginx.conf xxxxx@127.0.0.1:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
lost connection

scp -P 8080 nginx.conf xxxxx@127.0.0.1:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
lost connection
```

I've tried running these commands but it still doesn't work either.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I've also asked this question on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default the ssh server on the virtual machine will probably listen on port 22, which vagrant forwards to port 2222 on the host.

So you should be able to do:

```
scp -P 2222 nginx.conf xxxxx@127.0.0.1:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

You can change this with the port forwarding option you found, but you need to set up your ssh server on the guest accordingly (so forwarding port 80 doesn't do much if the ssh daemon is not listening on it).

Another way to make the guest visible from the outside, is to use a public network configuration - this way it can get an IP address from a DHCP server on the network (just like as if you connected a new physical machine), and afterwards it can be accessed via this address. You can do this in your Vagrantfile with:

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

Comment: Thanks Akos, I also found out that if you move your file on your host to your vagrant directory. It will be visible on your guest machine, so there's no need to scp.

Comment: The port may be different. `vagrant ssh-config` shows you the correct port.

Comment: @DanRubio is correct, that's the best solution. To control where the directory resides, uncomment this last line in your Vagrantfile:  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
   config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"